# How to type Redux compose

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I want to use Redux `compose` and type my component something like this:

```
compose(
  withOneThing,
  withSecondThing,
  connect<type1, type2>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(MyComp)
```

The question is how to do this the right way?
Now I use this hack:

```
as React.FC<PROPS>
```

But sometimes it is not possible and I do something like this:

```
 compose<any>(
      withOneThing,
      withSecondThing,
      connect<type1, type2>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    )(MyComp)
```

Is there a possible way to type `compose`, and not use `recompose` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

So the best way I found right now is next:

```
 compose<withOneThing_Type, withSecondThing_Type,connect_Type, MyComp_Type>(
  withOneThing,
  withSecondThing,
  connect<type1, type2>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(MyComp)
```

If there is a better way pls share.